# Docker: cannot open port 8080

Tags: curl, docker, port, containers

I have a REST API inside a container, binded to /rest/getMail, which returns a JSON string.

I can call this API inside the container, using `curl localhost:8080/rest/getMail` without problem.

However, I cannot call this API from outside, even though I already EXPOSE the port and did an external to internal port bind: `docker run -d -i -p 2500:8080 myimage`, or `docker run -d -i --expose 8080 -p 2500:8080 myimage`. It shows: connection refused.

I cannot even call the api using IP address like: `curl 172.17.0.2:8080/rest/getMail`

What can be the problem? It's really weird.
Thank you.

edit:

When I do `curl localhost:2500`, it shows:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

And `telnet localhost:2500`:

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

`curl localhost:2500/rest/getMail` gave me the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should be hitting the `host_ip:host_port` URL. Are you running the 2nd `curl` command on the host? If so, the port should be the mapped port (i.e. 2500, in your example).

Can you try running this on the host:

`curl localhost:2500/rest/getMail`

One more thing to check would be whether you have any firewall on the host that is blocking this connection.

Comment: Yes I did, the second one (curl localhost:2500/rest/getMail) does not work at all.

Comment: Hmmm, Could you please explain what you mean it does not work? Some more info would be very helpful! : )  also, could you try `telnet localhost 2500` and post the output?

Comment: ok thank you, yes I think you are right, the port is actually open, but I cannot get access to the API. But strangely if I call it from inside the container it works well.

Comment: Then you need to tell the application server that is serving this api to listen to another ip address... ; )  i assume it's just listening on the internal docker ip (172...) try listening on 0.0.0.0 to see if it works

Comment: @gsaslis I had a same problem, and your solution is working for me. Thanks :)